# How to correctly configure MoveIt! for each workspace?

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently learning MoveIt and was trying to understand how to setup up my workspaces. I was wondering if MoveIt is installed system-wide or do I have to include it in every workspace I build?

I installed MoveIt using the getting started tutorial: https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html

I created a workspace manually (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12RJro5bo3i2zhSXONtlAkdYqLYCvwM11?usp=sharing), added robot URDFs from different sources, and tried to create configuration files using MoveIt but was unsuccessful. I was only able to load the rrbot urdf provided in the tutorials and for that too I could not set the default joint poses in the setup assistant.

This is the error I get when I try to adjust poses for the rrbot -

```
![Unable to set pose for rrbot](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/16231640911731912.png)

This is the error I get when I try to include urdfs for other robots (BMDA3 Robot from https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman_experimental) (nothing happens when I try to click 'Show Default Pose', 'MoveIt', 'Edit Selected' or 'Add Pose') - 

![Error while loading Motoman BMDA3 URDF file](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/16231641115259853.png)
```

My setup is Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS Noetic.

Any help/advice/suggestion is greatly appreciated!

The error log associated with trying to seutp BMDA3 robot is as follows -

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://OR-LIN-9WG:41151/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.11

NODES
  /
    moveit_setup_assistant (moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [66874]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 5eba220a-c80f-11eb-87f1-8312c45d788f
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [66884]
started core service [/rosout]
process[moveit_setup_assistant-2]: started with pid [66887]
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ INFO] [1623125555.596477531]: Loaded motoman_bmda3 robot model.
[ INFO] [1623125555.597522304]: Setting Param Server with Robot Description
[ INFO] [1623125555.602743643]: Robot semantic model successfully loaded.
[ INFO] [1623125555.602767823]: Setting Param Server with Robot Semantic Description
[ INFO] [1623125555.613970597]: Loading robot model 'motoman_bmda3'...
[ INFO] [1623125555.614003429]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125555.631194793]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/base.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125555.631259380]: Link base has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125555.647209547]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125555.647240195]: Link torso_link_b1 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125555.663217312]: Error retrieving file 
...
[package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/right_link_e.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125555.774646430]: Link right_link_e has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125555.790151347]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/right_link_u.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125555.790183452]: Link right_link_u has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125555.805641765]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/right_link_r.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125555.805671995]: Link right_link_r has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125555.821017239]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/right_link_b.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125555.821049269]: Link right_link_b has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125555.836716193]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/right_link_t.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125555.836748975]: Link right_link_t has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125555.852355577]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125555.852384830]: Link torso_link_b2 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[ WARN] [1623125555.852485991]: No geometry is associated to any robot links
[ INFO] [1623125556.278199097]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1623125556.278251457]: OpenGL device: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2
[ INFO] [1623125556.278269864]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6).
[ INFO] [1623125556.340246501]: Loading robot model 'motoman_bmda3'...
[ INFO] [1623125556.340272562]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125556.357349378]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/base.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125556.357396482]: Link base has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125556.373206288]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125556.373241473]: Link torso_link_b1 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125556.388467197]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/left_link_l.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125556.388499190]: Link left_link_l has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125556.404846655]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/left_link_e.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
...
[package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/right_link_t.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125556.558025744]: Link right_link_t has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125556.572975118]: Error retrieving file [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl]: Package [motoman_bmda3_support] does not exist
[ WARN] [1623125556.573007854]: Link torso_link_b2 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[ WARN] [1623125556.573088735]: No geometry is associated to any robot links
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125556.588861523]: Could not load resource [package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/visual/base.stl]: Unable to open file "package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/visual/base.stl".
[ WARN] [1623125556.588984422]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/visual/base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
[ERROR] [1623125556.589077981]: Could not load model 'package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/visual/base.stl' for link 'base': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/visual/base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
[ WARN] [1623125556.589129405]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/visual/base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
[ERROR] [1623125556.589171361]: Could not load model 'package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/visual/base.stl' for link 'base': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/visual/base.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_bmda3_support' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[ERROR] [1623125556.605224231]: Could not load resource 
...
[ WARN] [1623125557.007202587]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
[ERROR] [1623125557.007229818]: Could not load model 'package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl' for link 'torso_link_b2': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
[ WARN] [1623125557.007259242]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
[ERROR] [1623125557.007334339]: Could not load model 'package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl' for link 'torso_link_b2': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://motoman_bmda3_support/meshes/bmda3/collision/torso_link.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)
[ INFO] [1623125557.059757898]: Loading Setup Assistant Complete
[ INFO] [1623125563.429005219]: -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ INFO] [1623125563.429040131]: Statistics:
[ INFO] [1623125563.429054666]:     18 : Total Links
[ INFO] [1623125563.429071491]:    153 : Total possible collisions
[ INFO] [1623125563.429082015]:      0 : Always in collision
[ INFO] [1623125563.429091508]:      0 : Never in collision
[ INFO] [1623125563.429100729]:      0 : Default in collision
[ INFO] [1623125563.429110446]:      0 : Adjacent links disabled
[ INFO] [1623125563.429120108]:    153 : Sometimes in collision
[ INFO] [1623125563.429132082]:      0 : TOTAL DISABLED
[ INFO] [1623125563.429166694]: Thread complete 0
================================================================================REQUIRED process [moveit_setup_assistant-2] has died!
process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/rwalia/.ros/log/5eba220a-c80f-11eb-87f1-8312c45d788f/moveit_setup_assistant-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[moveit_setup_assistant-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379810/how-to-correctly-configure-moveit!-for-each-workspace?/) by [Speedracer1702](https://answers.ros.org/users/75695/speedracer1702/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2021-06-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-06-08**:
Hello @Speedracer1702,

I have given you enough karma, now you can post images. Can you please! reupload images by pressing edit button below your question.

**Comment by [Speedracer1702](https://answers.ros.org/users/75695/speedracer1702/) on 2021-06-08**:
@Ranjit, thank you! I have included the images but it would not allow me to attach the error log (I think it only accepts image files, even for attachments). The google drive link should work however, let me know if there are any issues with that.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-06-08**:
For that, you have to copy your text and directly add it over here and make the formate to code by pressing the button near to the image.

**Comment by [Speedracer1702](https://answers.ros.org/users/75695/speedracer1702/) on 2021-06-08**:
I thought about doing that but the log is really long (387 lines).

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-06-08**:
It's okay you can post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial has you install MoveIt from source. That means, it is local to that workspace. When you source that workspace (`source /../../my_workspace/devel/setup.bash`), the MoveIt version in there takes precedence over anything else. It should be able to locate any debians you have installed but it won't be aware of packages in other workspaces. (Unless you are using overlayed workspaces, which seems unlikely.)

You can also install the MoveIt debians (`sudo apt install ros-melodic-moveit*`). If you do not have MoveIt cloned into your current workspace, then the debian version will be used.

I don't know what to say about the "package not found" errors except it seems like your workspace is not sourced correctly. Did you build this Motoman stuff from source or install a debian with `sudo apt ...`?

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2021-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Speedracer1702](https://answers.ros.org/users/75695/speedracer1702/) on 2021-06-09**:
I downloaded the motoman robot files from their git repo and then built my workspace. I believe I skipped sourcing the workspace (I feel stupid SMH). Everything works now! Thanks for pointing that out. Also, I installed the debian file and now it defaults to the system-wide installation folder (/opt/ros/noetic/share/moveit).